# How do I populate a string array upon instantiation?

Tags: c#

So I have created a class that holds properties for the names of albums, including their genre, name and artist with an array that will hold the track list. When compiled, the properties' default values are replaced however I don't know how to replace the default values for the array - I don't know how to replace the default track listing with new tracks for each album. Thanks.

Here is the CD.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise_2
{
class Cd
{
    string name;
    string artist;
    string genre;
    public string[] tracklist;
    public string[] newTracklist;

    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(string newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    public string getArtist()
    {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(string newArtist)
    {
        artist = newArtist;
    }

    public string getGenre()
    {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(string newGenre)
    {
        genre = newGenre;
    }


    public string[] getTracklist()
    {
        return tracklist;
    }

    public void setTracklist(string[] newTracklist)
    {
      string[] tracklist = newTracklist;
    }

    public Cd()
    {
        this.name = "CD Name";
        this.artist = "CD Artist";
        this.genre = "CD Genre";
        this.tracklist = new string[3] { "Track1", "Track2", "Track3" };
        this.newTracklist = new string[3] { "newTrack1", "newTrack2", "newTrack3" };
    }

}
}
```

And here is the main.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise_2
{
class Exercise2
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Cd CD1 = new Cd();
        CD1.setName("Kill 'Em All");
        CD1.setArtist("Metallica");
        CD1.setGenre("Thrash Metal");          

        Cd CD2 = new Cd();
        CD2.setName("Ride The Lightning");
        CD2.setArtist("Metallica");
        CD2.setGenre("Thrash Metal");

        Cd CD3 = new Cd();
        CD3.setName("Master Of Puppets");
        CD3.setArtist("Metallica");
        CD3.setGenre("Thrash Metal");

        Console.WriteLine(CD1.getName() + " - " + CD1.getArtist() + " - " + CD1.getGenre() + " - " + CD1.getTracklist());
        Console.WriteLine(CD2.getName() + " - " + CD2.getArtist() + " - " + CD2.getGenre());
        Console.WriteLine(CD3.getName() + " - " + CD3.getArtist() + " - " + CD3.getGenre());


    }
}
}
```

Comment: you should really use properties.

Comment: I'm gonna guess you came from a Java background?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you should be using properties, why not just create an array of CD?

Comment: Arrays are static data structure why not using `List<>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your setTracklist method creates a new array every time:

```
  public void setTracklist(string[] newTracklist)
    {
      string[] tracklist = newTracklist;
    }
```

Instead, you need to set the instance `tracklist` member:

```
  public void setTracklist(string[] newTracklist)
    {
      tracklist = newTracklist;
    }
```

One more piece of advice.  Don't create *methods* to get and set properties, it's just unnecessary work.  Change:

```
string name;
string artist;
string genre;
public string[] tracklist;
public string[] newTracklist;
```

To:

```
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Artist {get; set;}
public string Genre {get; set;}
public string[] Tracklist {get; set;}
```

You also might want to change `tracklist` to a `List<String>` so you can easily *add* tracks:

```
public List<String> Tracklist {get; set;}
```

If you do this, you can create a `Cd` instance a *lot* easier:

```
var newCD = new Cd
{
   Name = "Kill 'Em All",
   Artist = "Metallica",
   Genre = "Thrash Metal"
};

newCD.Tracklist.Add("Hit the Lights");
newCD.Tracklist.Add("The Four Horsemen");
newCD.Tracklist.Add("Motorbreath");
// etc etc
```

**Update:**

Here's the full code, in case something got mixed up.  I've also implemented a `getTracklist` method which returns all the tracks is a comma delimited form.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Cd
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Artist { get; set; }
  public string Genre { get; set; }
  public List<string> Tracklist { get; set; }

  public Cd()
  {
     Name = "CD Name";
     Artist = "CD Artist";
     Genre = "CD Genre";
     Tracklist = new List<string>();
  }

  public string getTracklist()
  {
     return String.Join(", ", Tracklist);
  }
}

public class Exercise2
{
  public static void Main()
  {
     Cd CD1 = new Cd();
     CD1.Name = "Kill 'Em All";
     CD1.Artist = "Metallica";
     CD1.Genre = "Thrash Metal";

     CD1.Tracklist.Add("Hit the Lights");
     CD1.Tracklist.Add("The Four Horsemen");
     CD1.Tracklist.Add("Motorbreath");

     Cd CD2 = new Cd();
     CD2.Name = "Ride The Lightning";
     CD2.Artist = "Metallica";
     CD2.Genre = "Thrash Metal";

     Cd CD3 = new Cd();
     CD3.Name = "Master Of Puppets";
     CD3.Artist = "Metallica";
     CD3.Genre = "Thrash Metal";

     Console.WriteLine(CD1.Name + " - " + CD1.Artist + " - " + CD1.Genre + " - " + CD1.getTracklist());
     Console.WriteLine(CD2.Name + " - " + CD2.Artist + " - " + CD2.Genre);
     Console.WriteLine(CD3.Name + " - " + CD3.Artist + " - " + CD3.Genre);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I tried some of the fixes you specified. However I get the error "Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I compile the program.

`namespace Exercise_2
    {
    class Cd
    {
        public string name
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string artist
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string genre
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public List<string> tracklist
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
 }`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I managed to get it working by adding a foreach loop that prints out each index add to the string. As you can tell I'm pretty new to programming.

Comment: Keep at it, it'll get less confusing!

Answer (score 1):

You would just write

```
CD1.setTrackList(new string[] {"Hit The Lights", "The Four Horsemen", "Motorbreath"});
```

And your `setTrackList` should read:

```
 public void setTracklist(string[] newTracklist)
 {
    tracklist = newTracklist;
 }
```

The way you originally wrote it, you were creating a new array of tracks each time you were setting it, instead of setting the backing property.

However, there is a better way to do this. C# has what's called [Auto Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). They handle all this for you.

```
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Artist {get; set;}
//.... etc
```

Comment: @MikeChristensen I was psyched that all three were Metallica CDs!